# for the given function compute the quotient...

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having problems understanding how to solve this equation.

compute for the given function `f(x+h)-f(x)/h` (where `h` is a constant).

function : `f(x) = -9x +12`

can somebody please explain to me how to solve this equation.?

Comment: ...it is not an equation.... if $f(x)=-9x+12$ what is $f(x+h)$?

Comment: I think you want $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. We have $f(x+h)=-9(x+h)+12=-9x-9h+12$. Subtract $-9x+12$ from this, divide by $h$. Things will simplify nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kind of operation that teachers call a "difference quotient". In the foundations of calculus, you will probably be working with this quotient and its properties when $h$ approaches $0$.

To evaluate, simply substitute:

$$\require{cancel}$$
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
$$\frac{-9(x+h) +12-(-9x +12)}{h}$$
$$\frac{-9x-9h+12-(-9x+12)}{h}$$
$$\frac{\cancel{-9x}-9h+12+\cancel{9x}-12}{h}$$
$$\frac{-9h+\cancel{12}-\cancel{12}}{h}$$
$$\frac{-9h}{h}$$
$$\boxed{-9} (h\neq0)$$

Because this function is linear, you will observe that $h$ is not involved in the final solution; however in many cases you will have $h$ left in the equation in some form.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped understand my problem

Comment: -1 if $h$ is indeed equal to zero then this is incorrect. Also you should have equals signs between the lines... you still have $h=0$... maybe explain to the OP why you don't want $h=0$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy At least how I was taught in NYS for the purposes of this pre-calculus concept, it was assumed $h\neq0$. Post corrected to specify this.

Comment: But you wrote $h=0$!

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Apologies, didn't see exactly what you were referring to at first.